# Don't Know where i am going wrong while flushing the stdin buffer in below code

Tags: c, while-loop, buffer, stdin

[I  have attached output image of my program. you can see the problem i am facing by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rprX.png)

Below code is my program to read an input from an user as character and check whether it is an alphabet or an number using my_isalpha() and my_isalnum() functions of my own versions of built in function isalpha() and isalnum().
Not working for second iteration of while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM     1
#define ALPHA   2
#define ASCII   3
#define BLANK   4


int main()
{
  char option;

  do
  {
      //declaration of function
      char character;
      int user_option, status;

      //get the character from the user
      printf("Enter the Character:");

      //clears both buffers to read the character
      fflush(stdin);
      fflush(stdout);


       //reads one character at a time
      character = getchar();

      //prompt the user for the option to check
      printf("Choice Below Option\n");
      printf("1.isalnum\n2.isalpha\n");
      printf("Enter your Option:");
      scanf("%d", &user_option);

      //validation of the user_option
      switch(user_option)
      {
          case 1:
                  status = my_isalnum(character);
                  if(status == NUM)
                  {
                      printf("Character '%c' is an number", character);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      printf("Character '%c' is not a number", character);
                  }
                  break;

          case 2:
                  status = my_isalpha(character);
                  if(status == ALPHA)
                  {
                      printf("Character '%c' is an Alphabet", character);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     printf("Character '%c' is not Alphabet",character);
                  }
                  break;
            default:
                 puts("Invalid Choice.....");
     }

    printf("\nDo you want to continue?[Y/N]:");
     scanf(" %c", &option);
 }while (option == 'Y' || option == 'y');
 fflush(stdin);
 fflush(stdout);
 return 0;
}
 //Function chaecks for the Number
 int my_isalnum(char character)
 {
   return (character >= '0' && character <= '9')?  NUM : -1;
  }

  //functionn checks for the alphabets
  int my_isalpha(char character)
  {
      return (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z' || character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') ? ALPHA: -1;

   }
```

above code works properly for the first time but during second iteration of while loop. when I give "Y" as an input code dirrectly jumps to user_option part of scanf .rather then waiting for "getchar()"- function.

Even after filushing the buffer using fflush() function i am not able to prompt the program for the character input.

Answer (score 1):

Flushing `stdin` is undefined behavior. Flushing is meant for output stream not input stream.

As per standard **§7.21.5.2**

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the
>   most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any
>   unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment
>   to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Also  `int getchar(void)` : `get char()` returns an `int`.

Quickfix: Remove `fflush(stdin)` from code.

```
printf("\nDo you want to continue?[Y/N]:");
     scanf(" %c", &option);
     getchar(); // this dummy getchar() will consume the `\n` from stdin.
 }while (option == 'Y')
```

#### Note:

Also as other solutions suggest to use `fpurge()` is an option but again it is *non-standard and non-portable*.

Comment: so how can i flush the input buffer to read my character for the second iteration @coderredoc

Comment: @MohmmedAsif.: Check my answer..put the dummy getchar...it will work

Comment: @MohmmedAsif.: This solution is portable..`__fpurge` is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
//clears both buffers to read the character
fflush(stdin);
```

`fflush()` doesn't clear `stdin` buffer as you expected. *`fflush()` is for flushing output stream like `stdout` not input stream `stdin`*.

To resolve this issue one way is to use extra `getchar()` to consume `\n` character. for example

```
scanf(" %c", &option);
getchar(); /* dummy getchar */
```

Also here

```
char character; /* change the type of character to int */
character = getchar();
```

`getchar()` return type is of `int` not `char`, you need to change the type of `character`. From the manual page of [getchar()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

```
int getchar(void);
```

Comment: Actually the one more `getchar` can be fatal too! you must check that's value too. If the user enters `aa\n` the input is now out of sync.